# call of overloaded 'begin(int)' is ambiguous

Tags: arduino, esp32

Ive got a ESP32-S2 and just try to test the circuit and the Board with this simple script.
Error Code says.

ziel_19-09-2020.ino: In function 'void setup()':
ziel_19-09-2020:85:18: error: call of overloaded 'begin(int)' is ambiguous
mcp1.begin(addr1);
^
In file included from C:\Users/Arduino\ziel_19-09-2020\ziel_19-09-2020.ino:1:
C:\Users\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MCP23017_Arduino_Library/Adafruit_MCP23017.h:26:8: note: candidate: 'void Adafruit_MCP23017::begin(uint8_t, TwoWire*)'
void begin(uint8_t addr, TwoWire *theWire = &Wire);
^~~~~
C:\Users\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MCP23017_Arduino_Library/Adafruit_MCP23017.h:27:8: note: candidate: 'void Adafruit_MCP23017::begin(TwoWire*)'
void begin(TwoWire *theWire = &Wire);
^~~~~
exit status 1
call of overloaded 'begin(int)' is ambiguous

The code is this

```
    #include <Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
#include "SPI.h" 

#define BUTTON_PIN   2   
#define PIXEL_PIN    6  
#define PIXEL_COUNT 136

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(PIXEL_COUNT, PIXEL_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp2;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp3;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp4;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp5;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp6;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp7;
Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp8;

///////////////////////////////////
/////////////Settings//////////////
///////////////////////////////////


int dotcolor_1=0;   
int dotcolor_2=250;
int dotcolor_3=0;

int circlecolor_1=250;
int circlecolor_2=0;
int circlecolor_3=0;

int time_hold=500;
int dtime=3;
///////////////////////////////////
/////////////Settings end//////////
///////////////////////////////////



#define addr1 0
#define addr2 1
#define addr3 2
#define addr4 3
#define addr5 4
#define addr6 5
#define addr7 6
#define addr8 7


double w=0;
double xd;
double yd;
boolean sensor_1[13];
boolean sensor_2[12];
boolean sensor_3[12];
boolean sensor_4[12];
boolean sensor_5[12];
boolean sensor_6[12];
boolean sensor_7[12];
boolean sensor_8[12];

int sen1[12];
int sen2[12];
int sen3[12];
int sen4[12];
int sen5[12];
int sen6[12];
int sen7[12];
int sen8[12];

uint16_t sensor1;
uint16_t sensor2;
uint16_t sensor3;
uint16_t sensor4;
uint16_t sensor5;
uint16_t sensor6;
uint16_t sensor7;
uint16_t sensor8;

void setup() {  
  strip.begin();
 mcp1.begin(addr1);
 mcp2.begin(addr2);
 mcp3.begin(addr3);
 mcp4.begin(addr4);
 mcp5.begin(addr5);
 mcp6.begin(addr6);
 mcp7.begin(addr7);
 mcp8.begin(addr8);

  for(int i=0;i<=15;i++){
  mcp1.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp2.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp3.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp4.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp5.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp6.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp7.pinMode(i, INPUT);
  mcp8.pinMode(i, INPUT);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `#define addr1 0` the compiler can't choose between `begin(pointer)` and `begin(int)`, because the value from `#define` could be a pointer.

If you set the I2C address as typed constant of type uint8_t, which is the type of the address parameter in the `begin` function with I2C address, the compiler will use the right function.

So set the addresses this way `const uin8_t addr1 = 0;`

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the Adafruit_MCP23017 library is bad. You may need to edit the library. There are actually two `begin` functions that you could *potentially* be calling, and Arduino has no idea which one you want.

**Option 1**:
You could add the following line outside of `setup()`:

```
#define Wire TinyWireM
```

and changing your `begin` functions to:

```
 mcp1.begin(addr1, &Wire);
 mcp2.begin(addr2, &Wire);
 mcp3.begin(addr3, &Wire);
 mcp4.begin(addr4, &Wire);
 mcp5.begin(addr5, &Wire);
 mcp6.begin(addr6, &Wire);
 mcp7.begin(addr7, &Wire);
 mcp8.begin(addr8, &Wire);
```

---

**Option 2**:
Currently, the two `begin` functions in the library look like this:

```
  void begin(uint8_t addr, TwoWire *theWire = &Wire);
  void begin(TwoWire *theWire = &Wire);
```

My recommendation above is based on the assumption that you are using the first function.

Your second option would be to remove the second function.

Remove the following from Adafruit_MCP23017.cpp (starting form line 133):

```
/**
 * Initializes the default MCP23017, with 000 for the configurable part of the
 * address
 * @param theWire the I2C object to use, defaults to &Wire
 */
void Adafruit_MCP23017::begin(TwoWire *theWire) { begin(0, theWire); }
```

Remove the following from Adafruit_MCP23017.h (line 27):

```
  void begin(TwoWire *theWire = &Wire);
```

I can further guide you in editing the library if needed

Comment: @Juraj Yes. The Neopixel library is irrelevant. If you google the meaning of ambiguous (which shows up in the error a few times), you’ll see it says something has two meanings. In the error, you’ll see there are two potential “candidates” for the function. These two functions make the call ambiguous. The Neopixel library and MCP library are separate and do not rely on each other.

Comment: the problem is the use of define. `const uin8_t addr1 = 0` would use the right version of begin

Comment: @Juraj Well, in your comment you initially referred to the Neopixel library. If you would be referring to the MCP library, I don't really know if your version would work. Originally I thought you said the Neopixel library not being initialized was messing with the MCP, which is wrong. But if OP used `const uint8_t addr1` for the MCP library, then it might work. However, I'm not wrong. My way would work. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that I'm not entirely sure that you're right, so I'm not going to include it in my post. If you think you're very sure you're right, then you can make yours.

Comment: changing the library if there is a simple solution in sketch?

Comment: @Juraj I did mention there are two options OP could use. One of them _is_ a solution in the sketch. Again, I am not sure if your method would work. Please post your own answer instead of repeatedly telling me my method is worse. OP will have their choice.

Comment: Both of you are correct - the MCP library interface has an ambiguous design which sucks, and the simplest workaround is calling begin() with a variable of specific type so the compiler can make a decision. In an ideal world the library's author should redesign this. But the person who asked the question doesn't need to remove methods from the library.